# Is it possible to simplify the meta data at the top of a MVC Razor file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

This doesn't really look so clean. Can I simplify this by putting all in just one curly brace?

```
@model Test.WebUx.Areas.Administration.ViewModels
@using Test.Shared.ExtensionMethods;
@{ Layout = "~/Areas/Administration/Views/_locs.cshtml"; }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The @model directive is required and has to be on it's own I believe.

You can however move "Text.Shared.ExtensionMethods" into the namespaces element in the web.config file in your Views folder and it will be imported on all of your views.  This is especially useful if these functions are used in multiple views.

Comment: +1 You can also use _ViewStart.cshtml or. vbhtml to set the Layout property for a whole folder of Views, which may enable you to remove that, too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do so. It's just like an HTML tagging system, but without any closing tag. To use Razor view engine, one uses @ to start the Razor code and fetch values that are being passed by controller.